# Trouble starting Python Threading loop

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, tkinter, chat

I am attempting to make a simple "chat" client in python. I have the basics and everything but I cannot get my threading to work at all. This is a still a work in progress so not all the code is there yet and I know that but if you do have any suggestion as a whole that would be greatly appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import socket
import thread
import threading

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5454
fromserver = ''
data = ''



#Declares socket information
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((HOST,PORT))


#Loop for receiving
def receivingloop():
    global fromserver
    while 1:
        fromserver = s.recv(30)
        time.sleep(.5)


class ChatClient:
    def __init__(self, master):

        #Use Global fromserver
        global fromserver
        global data
        #Create both frames        
        top_frame = Frame(master)
        bot_frame = Frame(master)
        #Create and pack the Buttons
        self.send_but = Button(bot_frame, \
                               text='Send',\
                               command=self.sending)
        self.quit_but = Button(bot_frame, \
                               text='Quit', \
                               command=client_window.destroy)        
        self.send_but.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.quit_but.pack(side=LEFT)




       #Create and pack label 
        self.received_lab = Label(top_frame,\
                                  text=(fromserver))        

        self.received_lab.pack()

        self.sent_lab = Label(top_frame,\
                              text='Message Sent: ' +data)

        self.sent_lab.pack()

        self.sending_entry = Entry(top_frame, \
                                   width=10)


        self.sending_entry.pack()

        #Pack Frames
        top_frame.pack()
        bot_frame.pack()


    #Function to send stuff          
    def sending(self):
        global data
        s.sendto(data,(HOST,PORT))
        data = str(self.sending_entry.get())
        print data


#Start the thread    
l1 = threading.Thread(target=receivingloop)
l1.start()


client_window = Tk()
chat_client = ChatClient(client_window)        
client_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken I would say the receivingloop method takes the self element but the self argument you need only by classes and this method is not in a class

Try this:

```
#Loop for receiving
def receivingloop():
    global fromserver
    while 1:
        fromserver = s.recv(30)
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: Also, it's advised to use queues to pass data to the GUI-thread of Tkinter: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm

Comment: It runs without error error now but it does not update the label. I know the server works because my other CLI receives the message and can print it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined with a variable called 'self', it looks like you previously had this function in a class, but decided to extract it from the class later on.

Anyway, to fix your problem, it should just be:

def receivingloop():

Note that the 'self' part from the function arguments has been removed.

Also, you might want to add `global data` to your send function.

Comment: I removed the self argument and I add the global data. I can send strings now but I cannot receive them still.

Edited the code to reflect this aswell.

Comment: I don't think there is a function which updates your label once you've sent data..


Also, i GUESS (I don't know too much about Tkinter) your label isn't dynamic, which means once it's initialized, if you change the variable's contents, the label won't be updated with it's latest contents. You have to do that yourself.


You probably want to update your label's text after you've sent it some data. Either create a signal to update, or call a function on your GUI. You could use a clock to periodically update the label to change the label to the last received piece of data.